# Tibco BW Container Edition Eclipse Interface

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

I am new to Tibco BWCE and I've just discovered that it uses the Eclipse IDE interface. My main problem is that I can't find anywhere a guide or documentation for the interface items.

[image: tibco ce eclipse]

[image: tibco ce process]

I just need a clear understanding of items numbered on the picture and their functionalities. I can't find anything useful about this from the Tibco site. Someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: The is a broad question. Have you used BW 6.X? There are YouTube videos on getting started. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnmoGGHHJldihlpqpg4g1DRZQUeY3PRBQ

Comment: The channel is useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the official documentation at this link
https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-activematrix-businessworks-6-4-2

Check the Getting started and application developement.